# Incomplete UTF8 char for UTF8 imbued std stream

Tags: c++, utf-8, locale, outputstream

I recently got a weird [bugreport](https://github.com/Return-To-The-Roots/s25client/issues/867).

The problem is that the following produces an incomplete UTF8 char on some machines:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
        std::cout.imbue(std::locale("fr_FR.UTF-8"));
        std::cout << 1337;
}
```

The output of this on my machine is "1 337" or in hex (via hexdump) "2031 3333 0037". But on the machine of the person with the bug the hex output is "e231 3333 0037".

The "e2" is the start of [zero width non joiner](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200c/index.htm) which is `e2 80 af` in UTF-8.

How is this possible? From my understanding the special char is the better number separator than a regular space, but why is C++(?) unable to fully print that out?

Hex output was gathered by `./a.out | hexdump` so console encoding shouldn't matter.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough. The output is "1 337" and the other is the hexadecimal representation (via hexdump see the bottom) of that string. I edited the question to clarify.

Comment: That hex output is already pretty weird... Why is it putting the space before the first digit? Is it doing spurious endianness conversions? And how is a null ending up in there?

Comment: @Sneftel I don't see how the code shown can produce the output shown, unless the STL locale being used is severely buggy, in which case it should be reported to the vendor of the STL implementation

Comment: @Sneftel That's how hexdump does it. Try it yourself, it seems to swap the high and low bytes for whatever reason. Maybe due to grouping in 2 byte words and endianess. But that is not the question. The question is about the "e2" vs "20" byte.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Which output are you refering to? The broken one (with "e2")? Then yes this is also what I'm thinking. But locales are complicated so I want to make sure I didn't miss anything. Otherwise please clarify.

BTW: Why the downvotes?

Comment: @Flamefire given the code shown, there is no reason why any locale should be producing either bytes `0x20` or `0x00` as your hex output claims. Do you get those same bytes if you print the number to a `std::ostringstream` or `std::ofstream` instead of to `std::cout`? Maybe this is just another unexpected side effect of running the output through hexdump and not in the STL itself?

Comment: Nope this is the locale in action: The thousand separator for "fr" is a space, or "20" in hex. This is exactly what I'm seeing there. The 00 seems to be simply the end-of string marker (again: 2byte words are swapped by hexdump)

Comment: @Flamefire, always make sure you use `-Cv` with `hexdump` otherwise you'll get the hex dump in words of 16-bits. This is why there's a `00` in the last word.